# Perl XML:DOM - Getting children at specific depth

Tags: perl, xmldom

I'm doing some XML parsing using Perl and decided on [XML::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aDOM). Assume I'm parsing a file containing the following:

```
<document>
   <A>
      <B/>
      <B/>
   </A>
   <B/>
</document>
```

The "B" element is processed differently depending on its relative location in the document (i.e. a B whose parent is A is different from a B whose parent is document). From a reference to to the document node, is it possible to get the B's that are immediate children. Then later, get a reference to the A node to get only the its child B's?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: @cjm: Thanks very much for the edit. I've been having a heck of time getting the thing to format properly. Now that I see how you did it, makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you know that all B elements will be children of either the document or an A, you can use the optional recurse parameter to [getElementsByTagName](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aDOM%3a%3aNode#getElementsByTagName).  Passing 0 means to return only direct child elements:

```
my @docB = $doc->getElementsByTagName('B', 0);
# do something with @docB

for my $aNode ($doc->getElementsByTagName('A')) {
  my @AB = $aNode->getElementsByTagName('B', 0);
  # do something with @AB
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another idea would be to load up [XML::DOM::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML%3a%3aDOM%3a%3aXPath), which makes these sorts of queries pretty natural, and way less verbose.

#### B nodes that are children of the document element:

```
@nodes = $doc->findnodes('/document/B');
```

#### B nodes that are children of A nodes that are children of the document:

```
@nodes = $doc->findnodes('/document/A/B');
```

#### B nodes that are immediate children of A nodes that occur anywhere:

```
@nodes = $doc->findnodes('//A/B');
```

#### B nodes that are descendants of any A node:

```
@nodes = $doc->findnodes('//A//B');
```

#### B nodes that have any one (exactly one) ancestor between them and the document:

```
@nodes = $doc->findnodes('/document/*/B');
```

And a whole lot more! (I threw a lot of options in there because it's not clear from your question which ones are exactly the options that are best suited to your problem).

Since all of the values are just ordinary XML::DOM objects with some methods added, you can mix and match with any existing XML::DOM code with nearly no fuss.